# Android Studio react-native assembleRelease bundleReleaseJsAndAssets failed

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio-3.0

what`s wrong with it when I run  assembleRelease   or  bundleReleaseJsAndAssets?

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
>       throw err;
>       ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/xxxx/xxxx/node_modules/react-native/cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)`enter code here`
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)